# SQL Table Joining

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join

I'm joining these three tables, but the same information gets displayed 3 times ... Any idea how to have only the unique rows to be displayed, as determined by unique shipment id's?

```
SELECT S.SHIPMENT_ID, S.CREATION_DATE, S.BUSINESS_ID, B.BUS_ID, S.SHIPMENT_STATUS, S.BUSINESS_NAME, S.SHIPMENT_MODES, S.CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM  "SHIPMENT" S
INNER JOIN "BUSINESS" B ON S.BUSINESS_ID=B.BUS_ID
INNER JOIN "SHIPMENT_GROUP" SG ON S.SHIPMENT_ID=SG.SHIPMENT_ID
INNER JOIN "DATA_GROUP" DG ON DG.ID=SG.GROUP_ID
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

try select distinct

SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting rows from the first table only, so this suggests that you are using the joins for filtering.

If so, you can rewrite this with `exists`, which will avoid duplicates if there are multiple matches. Starting from your existing query, the logic would be:

```
select s.*
from shipment s
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from business b 
        where b.bus_id = s.business_id
    ) and exists (
        select 1
        from shipment_group sg
        inner join data_group dg on dg.id = sg.group_id
        where sg.shipment_id = s.shipment_id
    )
```